# installing web logic: Unsupported major minor version 52.0

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, weblogic, java-7

I am trying to install `web logic` (point 3.6 in guide below)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_12_1_3.htm#EOHWL224

When running the below config.cmd file:

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL

@REM Determine the location of this script...
SET SCRIPTPATH=%~dp0
FOR %%i IN ("%SCRIPTPATH%") DO SET SCRIPTPATH=%%~fsi

@REM Delegate to the common delegation script...
CALL "%SCRIPTPATH%\fmwconfig_common.cmd" config_internal.cmd %*

SET RETURN_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%

pause

IF DEFINED USE_CMD_EXIT (

  EXIT %RETURN_CODE%

) ELSE (

  EXIT /B %RETURN_CODE%

)
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/oracle/ci
e/wizard/domain/WLSWizardConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:363)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController.createWizardConfiguration(Wiza
rdController.java:100)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController.main(WizardController.java:67)

Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I solve this? For reference I am using `Java 7`.

Comment: you'll need to update the jre against you are trying to run your application. The problem is it's older compared to the version used to compile the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in Java version mismatch. According to this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file here are java versions:

```
J2SE 9 = 53
J2SE 8 = 52
J2SE 7 = 51
J2SE 6.0 = 50
J2SE 5.0 = 49
JDK 1.4 = 48
JDK 1.3 = 47
JDK 1.2 = 46
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Seems that you expecting to use Java 7, which is 51, but actually have Java 8, which is 52

Comment: Except Installing WebLogic 12.1.3 shouldn't require Java8. Here is someone installing it with Java 7 : http://robinbuitenhuis.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-install-oracle-weblogic-server.html and documentation linked by OP also sugests using Java 7. I wonder what is the possible cause. Maybe installer got updated and it now requires Java8 even if installed application doesn't.

Comment: Either library was compiled with wrong version of Java or you are using wrong version of Java. You need to check both cases

Comment: how would I check? I ran the initial primary part of the install with java 7 and am trying the same now for 2nd part?